# Pick a file in Android without any file manager installed

Tags: android, android-intent, file-manager, filepicker

I tried picking a file from the internal or external storage with the code below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Of course it has `onActivityResult` method, and it's not the problem. It works fine in the modern phones or phones that have file manager installed. But the old one with no file manager throws

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT typ=file/* }

I tried switching to `ACTION_PICK` but no luck. I also tried `intent.setType("*/*");`, it didn't crash but the popup ask for action (videos, contacts,...) which is not true. I just want to pick any file not just a specified type.

I don't want to use any other file manager just to pick a file. Is there anyway I can get through this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that having the error explained, makes the solution much easier. So let me explain it to you:

You're starting an implicit intent. That means it's an intent that you know what you want to happen (use select a file) and you don't care which application will do it.

The error you're encountering is simply the system telling you (the developer), that there's no application installed that is capable of doing it (neither system nor 3rd party). There's simply no one capable of handling the action you want.

So you have two options from what I can see:

- `try-catch` the error

.

```
try {
   startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
   // maybe you should show a toast to the user here?
   Toast.makeText(context, "You need to install a file picker", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   // or maybe redirect to a 3rd party app that you know works
   startIntent(new Intent(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/... some app
}
```

- you can find a library or code to pick the file from inside your own app: http://bit.ly/1N1fZbO

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Looks like I have to ask user to install 3rd app

Answer (score 0):

Below code section should work for you!

```
Intent chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
chooseFile.setType("*/*");
Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE);
```

What's your Android version? Some android maybe not released with such activity.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention the android version. It's 4.0!

Comment: If `*/*`, it asks for "music track", "contact" and "gallery". Can't choose a file with that though. By the way, I use the emulator.